# How to display number of posts in author pane?

Tags: nodes

I have installed [Advanced Forum](https://drupal.org/project/advanced_forum) and [Author Pane](https://drupal.org/project/author_pane) modules.

Now I want to show user's post count instead of 'Last seen':

> Last seen: 2 weeks 6 hours ago

I could not see any guide in the docs so appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

it appears you need another module that will feed this info to author pane. This module is [User stats](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_stats).

Apparently though User stats has only a development release for D7 and reading through [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/1895824) issue, I would be reluctant to implement it on a production site. Will keep you updated if I find a better way to deal with this.

Edit: I've tested the 'post count' functionality of the 7.x-1.x-dev version of User stats and it seems to be working fine.